# String does not contain a definition for add method

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing a program in .NET. I am doing some changes in the program. I am getting a error

> String does not contain a definition for add method.

I don know how to rectify this error.

```
private string process(string fname)
{
  //string errs = "";
  string Strings = "";
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fname);
  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
  {
    string[] sa = lines[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    bool ok = false;
    if (sa[1].CompareTo("EQ") == 0)
      ok = true;
    if (!ok && sa[1].CompareTo("BE") != 0)
      continue;
    string name = sa[0];
    int token = NSECM.Lookup(name);
    if (token == 0)
    {
      //errs += "Symbol " + name + " not found\r\n";
      continue;
    }
    //int open = (int)(double.Parse(sa[2]) * 100 + 0.5);
    //int high = (int)(double.Parse(sa[3]) * 100 + 0.5);
    //int low = (int)(double.Parse(sa[4]) * 100 + 0.5);
    //int close = (int)(double.Parse(sa[5]) * 100 + 0.5);
    //uint vol = uint.Parse(sa[8]);
    //int date = cdate(sa[10]);
    //uint time = cvt(date);
    uint open = (uint)(double.Parse(sa[2]) * 100 + 0.5);
    uint high = (uint)(double.Parse(sa[3]) * 100 + 0.5);
    uint low = (uint)(double.Parse(sa[4]) * 100 + 0.5);
    uint close = (uint)(double.Parse(sa[5]) * 100 + 0.5);
    uint vol = uint.Parse(sa[8]);
    int date = cdate(sa[10]);
    //b.Append("D");
    b.Append("S" + (1000000 + token).ToString().Substring(1));
    b.Append("-" + date);
    b.Append("|D");
    b.Append(Encode.encode6(cvt(date)));
    //b.Append(Encode.encode6(time));
    b.Append(Encode.encode4(open));
    b.Append(Encode.encode4(high));
    b.Append(Encode.encode4(low));
    b.Append(Encode.encode4(close));
    b.Append(Encode.encode6(vol));
    //b.Append("\n");
    Strings.Add(b.ToString());
  }  
}
```

Comment: On what line do you receive the error?

Comment: There is no "Add" method defined for strings... is that not clear enough?  (it's the last line @Anders)

Comment: @JeffMercado yea tat is correct.but i don know how to solve it

Comment: your method returns a `string` object, why not simple return `b.ToString()` and delete the `Strings.Add(b.ToString());` line.

Comment: You could benefit from some better variable naming.  'b' isn't exactly indicative of anything.

Answer (score 3):

The `string` class does not define a method called `Add` therefore the line `Strings.Add(b.ToString())` does not compile. Depending on what you like to do there are 2 possible solutions i can imagine of

1. You want to combine the current value of `Strings` with the value of `b`: `Strings += b.ToString()`. But keep in mind that you are always appending stuff to the same StringBuilder so in the end you add to much. But on the other hand you can just write `Strings = b.ToString()` after the for-loop because then you have added all your text to the StringBuilder.
2. You want to add the current value of `b` as a new string to a collection of strings. In this case `Strings` should be a collection. The `Add` method suggests that you should have a look in the `List` class. `List<string> Strings = new List<string>();`. Now you can use `Strings.Add(b.ToString())`. But also here keep in mind that you are always appending to the same `StringBuilder` without flushing it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Add()` method on the `string` class:

```
Strings.Add(b.ToString());
```

You can concat the strings with the `+=` operator instead:

```
Strings += b.ToString();
```

Comment: better tell him to use `StringBuilder` for that as well no? as he's already using it for the inner for, and it beats string concatenation...

Comment: `StringBuilder` is better suited for this, but would require more changes. I just focused on the compiler error itself.

Comment: not really: just remove the `Strings.Add(b.ToString());` line, and add `return b.ToString();` after the for loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder instead of string. It supports append method to concatenate strings. Moreover StringBuilder is mutable. When we make use of the "StringBuilder" object, the Append method is used. This means, an insertion is done on the existing string. Operation on StringBuilder object is faster than String operations, as the copy is done to the same location. Usage of StringBuilder is more efficient in case large amounts of string manipulations have to be performed